# Databricks delta file to SQL table (Azure)

Tags: sql-server, dataframe, azure, scala, databricks

In Databricks I want to upload a Delta File to a table that already exists in SQL.  But I need that only the records that doesn`t exist are upload.

I am using this code:

```
%scala
val df = spark.read.format("delta").load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/hourly_tables_JMA/")

df.write 
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://qdenaz.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=database")
.option("dbtable", "[DWH].HOURLY_TABLES_JMA")
.mode("append")   
.option("user", "Admin")
.option("password", "****")
.save()
```

In mode option:

- If I use Append, I obtain duplicate records
- If I use Ignore, it doesn't do anything because the table already exists
- If I use Overwrite, it truncates the table and upload the records of the Delta File.

What other option can I use?   or what can I do to upload only the records of the Delta File that are not on the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To upsert non existing records in SQL table from data bricks it does not provide any specific writing mode only available [writing modes](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-write-modes-explained/) are **Append, Overwrite, Ignore, errorifexists** .

**To achieve your goal, follow below steps:**

- First read the delta table in Dataframe.

```scala
val df1 = spark.read.format("delta").load("<table_path>")
```

**My delta table DF:**

[image]

- Read table where you want to write the data from databricks in a dataframe.

```scala
val df2 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url","<JDBC_URL>")
    .option("dbtable","<Tablename>")
    .option("user", "<username>")
    .option("password", "<password>")
    .load()
```

**My SQL table DF:**

[image]

- Now with left anti join on primary key join the table to get non existing records in SQL table from delta table in dataframe.

```scala
val  df3 = df1.join(df2,Seq("<primarykey>"),"left_anti")
```

**My DF with non-existing records:**

[image]

- Now write this new dataframe with Non existing records in SQL table.

```scala
df3.write.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "<JDBC_URL>")
    .option("dbtable","<Tablename>")
    .option("user", "<username>")
    .option("password", "<password>")
    .mode("append")
    .save()
```

**Output:**

[image]